# Safari image not displaying

Tags: html, macos, safari

Images are displayed as blue question mark boxes when the src path is placed under ~/Library/Containers/ folder; safari can display the image just fine when I move the src path elsewhere like Documents or Downloads.

Chrome has no issue displaying images under ~/Library/Containers/ folder.

How do I get safari to display the image properly without moving my images to a different path?

Example Code:

```
<img src="/Users/administrator/Library/Containers/04E4CBB4-A3D9-4C91-A93B-D354340824D7/Data/Documents/filename.jpg" />
```

Comment: what's the directory structure starting with public_html?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<img src="../../Users/administrator/Library/Containers/04E4CBB4-A3D9-4C91-A93B-D354340824D7/Data/Documents/filename.jpg" />
```

if that doesn't work come back with your directory structure starting with public_html  also what path for ~